# Only one button can be in the "NO" state

Tags: angular, typescript

I developed a set of inputs, each input has a set of buttons that changes depending on the click.

Each button starts in the yes state, but if it is clicked it changes to the No. state.

Is there a way to put only one button in the No state? That is, if a button is already in the No state, when you click on another, that button changes to Yes and the last clicked to No.

Thanks!

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gggyko?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

**Code**

```
<div class="Submitcomments" *ngFor="let c of data; let  i = index;">
    <div>
        <div class="row rowComments" style="margin-top: 11px;">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <textarea  #myinput type="text" class="form-control AreaText" rows="2"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="row" style="margin-top: -20px; margin-left: 5px;">
            <button *ngIf="c.currentState=='pause'" class="btn reply" (click)="c.currentState='start'; focus()">Yes</button>
            <button *ngIf="c.currentState=='start'" class="btn reply1" (click)="c.currentState='pause'; focus()">No</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

data = [
    {    
        ID:1,
        Name : "Name",
        currentState: "pause"
    },
    {    
        ID:2,
        Name : "Name2",
        currentState: "pause"
    },
       {    
        ID:3,
        Name : "Name3",
        currentState: "pause"
    },
       {    
        ID:4,
        Name : "Name4",
        currentState: "pause"
    },
  ];
```

Comment: Either use radio buttons from Material or you need to call a function that iterates through your data and mutates the state the 'pause' on everything except the clicked element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go. Following up from my comment.

You can either use radio buttons like [these](https://material.angular.io/components/radio/overview) to auto toggle everything else

Otherwise each click will need to fire a function that iterates through the buttons and flips everything. Something like this:

```
adjustState(index) {
    for(var i = 0; i < this.data.length; i++){
        if(index != i){
          this.data[i].currentState =  'pause';
        }else{
          if(this.data[i].currentState == 'start'){
            this.data[i].currentState =  'pause';
          }else{
            this.data[i].currentState =  'start'; 
          }
        }
    }
  }
```

And call this in your buttons like

```
<button *ngIf="c.currentState=='pause'" class="btn reply" (click)="adjustState(i); focus()">Yes</button>
```

Demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-amuslc)

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way that if you click the button again it goes to the original Yes? In other words, I clicked the button, it goes to No, if I click that same button again, it goes to Yes again.

Comment: @Paulsk updated the answer and the demo. Feel free to collapse ifs as you see fit

Answer (score 1):

You can bind the text of the button from json property and change it as and when required.

Try like this:

.ts

```
 changebtnText(index) {
    this.data.forEach((item, i) => {
      if (i == index) {
        item.currentState = item.currentState == "start" ? "pause" : "start";
      } else {
        item.currentState = "pause";
      }
    });
  }
```

.html

```
<button class="btn reply" (click)="focus();changebtnText(i)">{{c.currentState == 'start' ? 'No' : 'Yes'}}</button>
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jat966?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way that if you click the button again it goes to the original Yes? In other words, I clicked the button, it goes to No, if I click that same button again, it goes to Yes again.

Comment: I have changed the demo, check

Comment: You realize a lot! If I want to keep only the currentState on the object and not btnText, is there a way to put it to work only with currentState, just following this order?  ' if(index != i){
          this.data[i].currentState =  'pause';
        }else{
          this.data[i].currentState =  'start';
        }'

Comment: I tried to follow your logic of thought but it didn't work

Comment: Check the modified Demo

Comment: Modified the answer without using `btnText` property

Answer (score 1):

You can only add a toggle method for change status.

[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/only-one-button-can-be-in-the-no-state?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

**app.component.html**

```
<div class="row" style="margin-top: -20px; margin-left: 5px;">
    <button class="btn reply" (click)="focus();toggleButton(i)">{{c.currentState == 'start' ? 'No' : 'Yes'}}</button>
</div>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
toggleButton(index) {
    this.data[index].currentState = this.data[index].currentState == "start" ? "pause" : "start";
}
```